# Model won't display in GE Plugin Tour Player

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin

Does the GE Plugin Tour Player feature support showing a model from a .kmz file? If so I'm not able to get that to work.

Here is a test page I have set up:
http://www.ppacg.org/google_earth/ds/tip/8th-Street-Tour-Model.html

There is a model in this .kmz showing a future highway improvement. This model displays on the tour when using the Desktop GE application, but not on the GE Plugin. I checked the paths on  and  and they look okay. I used this code from the Google Earth API Samples - Playing Tours for my starting point:
http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/tour-player.html

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the page an the Tour works perfectly. That said you do have a couple of errors on the page.

Firstly, remove the line

```
document.getElementById('installed-plugin-version').innerHTML =
  ge.getPluginVersion().toString();
```

It is giving the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

Also, the path to the css file is incorrect. You have

```
http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/static/prettify.css
```

It should be

```
http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/static/prettify/prettify.css
```

Finally, instead of using the lines

```
var href = window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/')) + '/';
    href += '../8thStreet1a.kmz';
```

You could just directly link to the file:

```
var href = "http://www.ppacg.org/google_earth/ds/8thStreet1a.kmz"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Fraser, I've made those changes and the model layer is displaying now!

Comment: Good stuff - if you mark the answer as accepted people will be more likely to help in the future too.